# Size of Mantel Needed to Protect a TV

Tags: fireplace, television

I am remodeling my fireplace, installing a vented gas fireplace unit.

I will hang a TV above the fireplace and use a stone mantel to deflect the heat from the fireplace away from the TV.  The mantel will be mounted 8 inches below the TV.

How far out from the TV does the mantel need to extend to be effective in protecting the TV from heat?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/14214555047052729/)*</sup>

Indeed a tv mounted over a fireplace is not ideal for viewing comfort.

There are minimum clearances that must be observed for safety reasons.

As you can see the further out a mantel protrudes the higher it has to be.

The question becomes “how far out from the wall will my tv protrude?
That will determine how far a mantel will need to protrude to deflect heat away from tv.
For reference the front of my 2016 era 65” inch Samsung on a full motion bracket sits off the wall about 9” when fully retracted.
If over a fire place I would want at least a 12” mantel to deflect the heat.
If you are determined to have a tv above a fire place you can see that the center of a large screen will be well above  the optimal height of approx 42” from floor.

However many TVs are set higher than optimal and if your room is large enough to allow seating far back from the fireplace the viewing comfort is not as adversely effected as in smaller rooms with high mounted tv.

Edit I just re read your question and see that your  mantel is stone so not a combustible material.
You could probably get away with a smaller clearance from top of fire box to bottom of mantel.

Comment: Did you draw that figure? If not you have to provide attribution where it came from.

Comment: @MichaelKaras  it was a simple google image search  the image was on a Pinterest page. It is not clear who produced it

Comment: I believe you have to make best effort. That may be that you provide a link to where you found it. I have edited your answer to show one technique on how this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Do not put the TV above the fireplace. There are many reasons to not do what you propose and the heat from the fireplace is just one of them.

The main argument should be regarding your neck. Optimum viewing of a TV screen is straight on. The best location for the TV screen is that the center of the screen be at the same level as your eyes when you are sitting in the viewing area. Even if you try tilting the face of the TV down at an angle from high on the wall your neck will take strain as you have to lean your head back to peer at such placement.

There is another consideration that has to be taken into account as well. This will depend entirely on how the wall surface in front of the chimney is built. I have seen some installations where drywall is mounted on just thin boards with wide spacing in front of the chimney surface. Not at all a suitable strong framing structure to be using for mounting a TV bracket.